# Toggle Class sequentially

Tags: jquery, queue, timeout, sequence, settimeout

I'm trying to toggle class for elements sequentially. I got this code I found and modified to work, but only with fade:

```
    $('.desplegable').click(function() {
            
    var lis = $(this).parent().find('.pops');
    var delay = 0;
    
    lis.each(function() {
        var $li = $(this);
        $li.queue('fade', function(next) {
            $li.delay(delay).fadeIn(0, next);
        });
        
        $li.dequeue('fade');
        
        delay += 100;
    });
});
```

is it possible to do it with toggle class? something like this, but here the sequence doesn't work

```
$('.desplegable').click(function() {
            
    var lis = $(this).parent().find('.pops');
    var delay = 0;
    
    lis.each(function() {
        var $li = $(this);
        $li.queue('toggle', function(next) {
            $li.delay(delay).toggleClass('appear', next);
        });
        
        $li.dequeue('toggle');
        
        delay += 100;
    });
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<div>
<div class="desplegable">Title</div>
<div class="pops">Element 1</div>
<div class="pops">Element 2</div>
<div class="pops">Element 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would help a lot if you could provide the relevant html code so we can test it.

Comment: I edited the question with html, thanks and sorry

Comment: Your issue is that class changes `addClass` `toggleClass` etc do not go on the animation queue, so are not affected by `.delay()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `fadeToggle()` with an incremental delay on each `.pops` element in the set.

This can also be extended to reverse the order of the fade when hiding the elements on successive clicks:

```js
$('.desplegable').click(function() {
  var $pops = $(this).parent().find('.pops').stop();      
  if ($pops.eq(0).is(':visible'))
    $pops = $($pops.get().reverse());
    
  $pops.each((i, el) => $(el).delay(100 * i).fadeToggle(300)); 
});
```

```css
.pops { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="desplegable">Title</div>
  <div class="pops">Element 1</div>
  <div class="pops">Element 2</div>
  <div class="pops">Element 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: fadeToggle will do the trick thanks so much!